# How to create a pull-down menu in Django?

Tags: python, django, select, choicefield

I try to create a pull-down menu in Django, but there is no such a menu in the output.

Here is my view.py:

```
class MajorProgramForm(forms.Form):
    major_programs = forms.ChoiceField(label="Major Programs", choices=MAJORS, required=True)

def choose_major_program(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = MajorProgramForm(request.GET)
    context["form"] = form
    return render(request, "program.html", context)
```

And here is my template.py:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Choose Your Courses</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Choose Your Courses</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="frame">
            <form name="form", action="{% url 'choose_major_program' %}" method="GET">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <ul>
                {% for option in form.major_programs.choices %}
                    <li>{{ option.name }}</li>
                {% endear %}
                </ul>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Below is the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^$', choose_major_program, name="choose_major_program")]
```

And the result is this:
[A web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxGob.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I  guess you want something like which is a select input

```
<select name="major_choice">
{% for option in form.major_programs.choices %}
    <option>{{ option.name }}</option>
{% endear %}
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! After editing my code,  there is a drop-down box in the output but the drop-down box is empty.